# Using handlebars in Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, handlebars.js, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to develop a prototype using Firebase.

I am using Firebase function. My package.json file in function directory is:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.15.4",
    "firebase-admin": "~4.2.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.5.7",
    "hbs": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

My index.js file looks like:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const hbs = require('hbs');

var app = express();
app.set('view engine', hbs);

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.getMessages = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    var abc = admin.database().ref('/messages').on("value", function(snapshot) {
        res.send(snapshot.val());
      }, function (errorObject) {
        console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
      });

  });

  exports.showMessage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    res.render('about.hbs' , {
      pageTitle : 'About Page',
      currentYear  : new Date().getFullYear()
    });
  });
```

While "getMessage" function works fine, I get an error while executing "showMessage" function which uses third party module HBS.

Function Logs show

```
Error: Cannot find module 'hbs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at new View (/var/tmp/worker/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:50:49)
    at EventEmitter.app.render (/var/tmp/worker/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:545:12)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (/var/tmp/worker/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:938:7)
    at exports.showMessage.functions.https.onRequest (/user_code/index.js:46:9)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:26:47)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:635:7
```

Answer (score 4):

What you've done here is created a new express app and set its default view engine to hbs:

```
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', hbs);
```

But that doesn't cause Cloud Functions to do anything with that app.  The `app` object you just created is just sitting there, unused.

If you want to use an express app with Cloud Functions, you'll also have to pass it along to onRequest:

```
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

This means you'll also have to configure endpoints on the express app so it knows what URL paths to service.

If you want to use handlebars with Cloud Functions, why don't you start with [this sample project](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/template-handlebars) from the Firebase team?

Comment: One good reason to not start with the sample project is that the page no longer exists. Doug, are there any other sample projects that show how to use Handlebars with Cloud functions?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the answer above. What you need to do is install handlebars and consolidate package. then write the following codes..

```
const express = require('express');
const engines = require('consolidate');
const app = express();
app.engine('hbs', engines.handlebars);
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.render('index', {
    title: 'Page Title'
  });
});
```

this is just a sample that works for me everytime.. I hope you can build upon this..make sure you create your `views`. Usually this is how my structure looks.

```
functions
 src
  index.ts
 views
  layouts
  partials
```

All the best man.

Your files should be *.hbs extension